# Why does deleting a TStringList pointer throw an exception?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++builder, tstringlist

I am using Embarcadero C++ Builder.

I have a function that declares a `TStringList`, uses it throughout the function, then `delete`s the object at the end of the function.

I have been using this code happily as a 32 bit application and have converted it to a 64 bit application, and now I get an "Invalid Pointer Operation" exception when trying to delete the `TStringList`.  Any ideas?

The odd thing is I had the same trouble with another function that uses a character pointer (using `new` to create heap memory space) and a `delete` operation.  I ended up creating a local buffer with stack space for that function, but I'm stuck with this one since I would like to use the `TStringList` object.

Here is the code:

```
String ReadUserConfig(String ConfigString) {
    String UserConfigPath = AppDrive + "\\DC\\userconfig.csv";

    TStringList *List = new TStringList;


    if (FileExists(UserConfigPath)) { // file present, parse it
        try {
            List->LoadFromFile(UserConfigPath);
            delete List;
        }
        catch(...) {
            ShowMessage("Exception in ReadUserConfig()");
            return ReturnString;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < List->Count; ++i) {
            String thisLine = List->Strings[i];

            /* search for ConfigString in this line */
            if ((thisLine.Pos(ConfigString) != 0) &&
                (thisLine.Pos("USER_CONFIG") != 0)) {
                /* grab everything right of ConfigString */
                thisLine = thisLine.SubString
                    (thisLine.Pos(ConfigString) + ConfigString.Length() + 1,
                    thisLine.Length());
                ReturnString = thisLine.Trim();

                i = List->Count;
            }
        }

    }

    delete List;  /* CAUSES INVALID POINTER EXCEPTION */
    return ReturnString;
}
```

Comment: Because you've already deleted `List`, in your `try` statement? `List->LoadFromFile(); delete List;` seems pretty silly, when you're repeatedly using `List` in the block after the `catch`.

Comment: You have use-after-`delete` and double-`delete` bugs in this code, as well as a memory leak. Why are you `delete`ing `List` in the `try` block? You obviously want it to stick around so that you can perform the operations in the `for` loop later. Plus, if an exception *is* thrown from the `try` block and caught, `List` won't actually be `delete`ed. Perhaps the more important question here, though, is why you are dynamically allocating `List` at all, since apparently it isn't ever supposed to outlive this function? Just put it on the stack, and problem solved.

Comment: @acwaters what you say about the stack is generally true for purely C++ code, but this is not pure code. `TStringList` is a `TObject` descendant, and `TObject` can only be constructed on the heap, not the stack. This is a compiler compatibility restriction due to `TObject` being implented in Delphi Pascal, and all Delphi class objects are heap-based.

Comment: From the look of your code, you probably meant the first `delete List` to be in the catch black, not in the try block

Comment: I'll echo @acwaters - don't use a pointer at all. This doesn't seem to be an appropriate time for dynamic allocation. Try: `TStringList List;`, and access it like `TStringList.something` instead of `TStringList->something`. Also, you code could be greatly simplified by using standard containers and utilities.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ahh, okay; that makes sense. I'm not familiar with Delphi, clearly. In any case, the rest of my comment stands.

Comment: For example, your iteration, check, and return could be shortened to `for (auto str : strings)` ⏎ `auto start = str.find(substring);` ⏎ `if (start != string::npos) return string(str.begin() + start, str.end());`

Comment: Good catch Steve.  I meant the delete to be in my catch block.  Thanks all.

Comment: @JimV  Delphi-style classes must be allocated with new - therefore my use of delete.

Comment: @martinarcher Could you wrap it in a managed pointer? That would free you from having to manually manage the memory. `unique_ptr<TStringList> List = make_unique<TStringList>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in comments, your code has logic bugs in it, causing you to `delete` the `List` twice, or leak it completely.

Try something more like this instead:

```
String ReadUserConfig(String ConfigString) {
    String UserConfigPath = AppDrive + "\\DC\\userconfig.csv";

    try {
        TStringList *List = new TStringList;
        try {
            if (FileExists(UserConfigPath)) { // file present, parse it
                List->LoadFromFile(UserConfigPath);

                for (int i = 0; i < List->Count; ++i) {
                    String thisLine = List->Strings[i];

                    /* search for ConfigString in this line */
                    if ((thisLine.Pos(ConfigString) != 0) &&
                        (thisLine.Pos("USER_CONFIG") != 0)) {
                        /* grab everything right of ConfigString */
                        thisLine = thisLine.SubString(thisLine.Pos(ConfigString) + ConfigString.Length() + 1, thisLine.Length());
                        ReturnString = thisLine.Trim();    
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        __finally {
            delete List;
        }
    }
    catch(const Exception &e) {
        ShowMessage("Exception in ReadUserConfig()\n" + e.Message);
    }
    catch(...) {
        ShowMessage("Exception in ReadUserConfig()");
    }

    return ReturnString;
}
```

Or, use a `std::auto_ptr` (pre C++11) or `std::unique_ptr` (C++11 and later) instead of a `try/finally` block:

```
#include <memory>

String ReadUserConfig(String ConfigString) {
    String UserConfigPath = AppDrive + "\\DC\\userconfig.csv";

    try {
        //std::auto_ptr<TStringList> List(new TStringList);
        std::unique_ptr<TStringList> List(new TStringList);

        if (FileExists(UserConfigPath)) { // file present, parse it
            List->LoadFromFile(UserConfigPath);

            for (int i = 0; i < List->Count; ++i) {
                String thisLine = List->Strings[i];

                /* search for ConfigString in this line */
                if ((thisLine.Pos(ConfigString) != 0) &&
                    (thisLine.Pos("USER_CONFIG") != 0)) {
                    /* grab everything right of ConfigString */
                    thisLine = thisLine.SubString(thisLine.Pos(ConfigString) + ConfigString.Length() + 1, thisLine.Length());
                    ReturnString = thisLine.Trim();    
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(const Exception &e) {
        ShowMessage("Exception in ReadUserConfig()\n" + e.Message);
    }
    catch(...) {
        ShowMessage("Exception in ReadUserConfig()");
    }

    return ReturnString;
}
```